# math function wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text input called "textmoney". In my jQuery i have a variable called "dailyE". This var is basically "textmoney".val / 365. This whould show an estimated amount made daily. What i can't get to work is my "stats", which basically show statistics of the number inputted in "textmoney". I can't get it to display a simple math function in statFunction. I've tried to fix this for a while now.

here is my jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {


    var $demo = $('#demo');
    var $textMoney = $('#textmoney');
    var $moneydiv = $('#moneydiv');
    var $stat = $('#stat');

    var dailyE = $textMoney.val() / 365;
    var $second = (dailyE / 24) / 60 / 60 / 60;
    var $minute = (dailyE / 24) / 60 / 60;
    var $hour = (dailyE / 24);
    var $day = dailyE;
    var $week = dailyE * 7;
    var $month = (dailyE * 7) * 30;
    var $year = (dailyE * 7) *30 *12;

    var $secondp = $('#second');
    var $minutep = $('#minute');
    var $hourp = $('#hour');
    var $dayp = $('#day');
    var $weekp = $('#week');
    var $monthp = $('#month');
    var $yearp = ('#year');

    $('#stat').hide();

    function getmoney(){
        var money = $textMoney.val();
            if (isNaN(money) || money === '') {
                $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
            } else {
                var dailyE = $textMoney.val() / 365;
                $demo.text('$' + dailyE + ' per day');
            }
    }

    function statFunction() {
        $stat.show();

        $secondp.text("$second");
    }

    // on enter key
    $textMoney.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            getmoney();
            $('#stat').show();
        } else if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $demo.text('');
            $('#stat').hide();
        }
    }).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey');
    });

    // on click 
    $moneydiv.click(function(){    
        getmoney();
        $('#stat').show();
     });

     $stat.click(function() {
        statFunction();
     })

});
</script>
```

Comment: Suggest you create a demo with corresponding html for this in jsfiddle.net. Will get far better response when people can test this in browser

Answer (score 0):

missing $ for  `var $yearp = ('#year');`

Please correct it as

```
var $yearp = $('#year');
```